# How to start and stop ejbs from outside jboss

Tags: jboss, jakarta-ee

i am developing java ee 5 app based on jboss4.2.3, one of project milestones is to create web-admin tool to stop or restart ejb modules of the application

any idea  how to achieve this ?, i appreciate if some one recommend a short developer guide for jboss

Comment: What is your application doing? What's the point to restart them? There is normally not concept of start/stop but only of deployment/undeployment. What you are doing is re-inventing the admin console, why would you do that?

Comment: having a unique ide to admin all the components and customize the options is required , low level technical admin is the target consumer for the admin part

Answer (score 0):

As ewernli commented, you're re-inventing.  Check your [jmx-console](http://community.jboss.org/wiki/JMXConsole).